# What's the difference between 懒惰 and 懒?

Tags: difference

What's the difference in the usage between 懒惰 and 懒? Both can be translated as "lazy".

Comment: what source would just say "lazy" for both?,  cf. bkrs:  **懶** 、 嬾
(1) (形声。 从心, 赖声。 本义: 懒惰)
(2) 同本义 [lazy; indolent; slothful]
懒, 懈也。 怠也。 一曰卧也。 --《说文》。 字亦作懒。
吾少懒学问, 晚成人。 --《宋书·范晔传》
(3) 又如: 懒待(没有精神和兴致); 懒怠(懒于做某种事); 懒得(不想, 不情愿); 懒残和尚煨芋(唐衡狱寺和尚明瓒禅师, 性子懒惰, 常吃别人剩食, 因号懒残。 李泌在寺里夜读访他时, 他正在牛粪中煨芋, 并送半个芋头给李, 叫他小心不要多讲话, 去做十年宰相。 后果如其言)
(4) 疲惫 [sluggish; drowsy]。 如: 懒困(疲倦困怠); 懒怯(疲倦虚弱)
偷懒 unwilling to work
好吃懒做 caring for nothing but eating; be gluttonous and lazy
人勤地不懒。 Where the tiller is tireless, the land is fertile.
（疲倦; 没力气） sluggish; languid:
伸懒腰 stretch oneself
身上发懒 feel languid (drowsy)

Comment: **懒惰**  (1) [lazy; slothful]∶偷懒; 不喜欢费体力或脑力
有天赋却懒惰的艺术家
(2) [indolent]∶不勤快
这对懒惰的作家是个刺激 also find 100 samples for each, **懒**  used predicatively or with following verb (loath to), or with 于 (unlike 懒惰)  **懒惰**  used attributively or predicatively, also as noun, laziness

Comment: "100 samples" in preceding comment refers to jukuu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 懒 (lazy) is mainly an adjective (less often as a noun)

Example:

**懒**人 (**lazy** person)

人**懒** (the person is **lazy**)

> 懒惰 (lazy/ laziness) can be an adjective or a noun.

Example:

由于他**懒惰**，他的花园里充满了杂草 (Due to he being **lazy**, his garden is full of weeds )

由于他的**懒惰**，他的花园里充满了杂草 (Due to his **laziness**, his garden is full of weeds )

> The adjective 懒惰 preceding a noun usually requires the adjectival prefix '的'

Example: **懒惰的**人 (**lazy** person)

> The adjective 懒惰 after a noun doesn't require adjectival prefix '的'

Example:人**懒惰** (the person being **lazy**)

Answer (score -1):

懒 (lazy) can also be a noun. It is used more often in spoken language compared with 懒惰(lazy).
(Adding to @Tang Ho's answer)

Comment: compare to 懒惰, 懒  is more often be used as an adjective than being a noun. It is uncommon to say 由于 [他的懒]，他的花园里充满了杂草.  懒惰 on the other hand, is equally common to be used as a noun as an adjective.